# Mark as read/unread button data sheet php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to coding and I'm using php and mysql to make a admin panel to show clients data from a form.
Now I want to make a button to show wether the data has been processed or not. 
The idea is, I have a column named star and if star == read that display "green" and if star =! read display "red". 
Then if the button is pressed, if star == read update to unread but if star =! read update to read.

I have the button like this:

```
<td><a href=\"read.php?id=".$row['id']."\" class=\"buttonize\">star</a></td>
```

And read.php like this:

```
<?php
include("db.php");
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $query = "UPDATE users SET star='read' WHERE id = '$id'";
 mysqli_query($link, $query) or die('Database error!');

 header('location:admin_main.php');
?>
```

This just updates the row to read and doesn't have the ability to become unread again.
But I don't know how to formulate the if statements.

If anyone has any suggestions, that is much appreciated.

EDIT

To show a bit of what I tried:

I added a new column to the data sheet:

```
<td>".$star."</td>
```

And then I tried to use the code below to check the database:

```
$query = "SELECT star FROM users";
 $selectie = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die($query."<br>".mysql_error());

 if($selectie == 'read') {
    $star = 'read';
    } else {
    $star = 'unread';
  }
```

And for the read.php:

```
<?php
 include("inc/verbinden.php");
 $id = $_GET['id'];

 $query = "SELECT star FROM users";
 $selectie = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die($query." <br>".mysql_error());

 if($selectie == 'read') {
 $query = "UPDATE users SET star='unread' WHERE id = '$id'";
 mysqli_query($link, $query) or die('Database error!');
 } else {
 $query = "UPDATE users SET star='read' WHERE id = '$id'";
 mysqli_query($link, $query) or die('Database error!');
}


header('location:admin_main.php');
?>
```

But I realize that the if/else is wrong.

Comment: What you need to do is to query the row in a SELECT statement and checking if either equals to "read/unread". If you want, you can also use two buttons; one for "read" and one for "unread", but that could confuse the user. That, or use an `if/else` statement and run different queries that have the `SET star='read'` or `SET star='unread'` respectively.

Comment: So, have you written/tried anything based on what I've written above yet? I could easily write this for you, but then you'd of not have learned anything. This was a question btw, one I'd like to get a response from, just as you have, asking a question with a response ;-)

Comment: I edited the post above as a response to your question.

Comment: I noticed. I was away for a bit and have since posted something below that you can look at and try. See the notes also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. What you missed is looping over (successful) results, such as using a [`while` loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) for instance:

Side note: I added `(int)` for the GET array which helps to safeguard against a possible [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and corrected the use of `mysql_error()`. That api does not intermix with the mysqli_* api.

```
<?php
 include("inc/verbinden.php");

 if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
     $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
     }else{
         echo "The GET array is empty.";
         exit; // Stops further execution.
     }

 $query = "SELECT star FROM users";
 $selectie = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die($query." <br>".mysqli_error($link));

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectie)){
         if($row['star'] == 'read') {
         $query = "UPDATE users SET star='unread' WHERE id = '$id'";
         mysqli_query($link, $query) or die('Database error!'); // use mysqli_error($link)
         }else{
         $query = "UPDATE users SET star='read' WHERE id = '$id'";
         mysqli_query($link, $query) or die('Database error!'); // use mysqli_error($link)
            }
        }

header('location:admin_main.php');
exit; // Stops further execution.
```

Note: You could substitute `mysqli_fetch_array()` with `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`.

Also, it's best to use `mysqli_affected_rows()` when using UPDATE in order to get actual truthness.

You can read up on those functions:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

One thing to note though is that `read` and `Read`, as well as `unread` and `Unread` are two different animals. So make absolutely sure that those are indeed the values in your database as well is what is going in the database.